# For applying to math postdocs on mathjobs, does "N Reference Letters" include one for teaching?

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, recommendation-letter, application

I'm a graduate student in the US, currently applying for postdoc positions on the [mathjobs](https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs) website. The format of the job postings is basically a description of the position, followed by

> **Application Materials Required**
>   Submit the following items online at this website to complete your application:
>
> - Curriculum Vitae
> - Research Statement
> - ...
> - N Reference Letters (to be submitted by the reference writers at this site)
>
> And anything else requested in the position description.

(where N is usually 3 or 4).

Sometimes, the position description says explicitly

> N letters of recommendation, *one of which should address the candidate’s teaching qualifications.*

### My question

If the position description does ***not*** have an explicit statement asking for a teaching recommendation letter, is it supposed to be one of the N letters I submit to them anyway? Or, should I submit N letters all having to do with my research? Is there any harm in submitting N + 1 letters in order to include my teaching recommendation letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience serving on large numbers of pure mathematics search committees at a couple of different research universities, people who read the files are often only dimly aware of what the ad requests.  The vast majority of files will contain 4 research letters and 1 teaching letter.  Even if they only ask for 3 research letters, it is a poor idea to not include a 4th if you have one since most people will have 4.

Some people go overboard and submit a ton of research letters (I've seen 8-9 in a single file).  This can also cause problems: 1. usually when someone has that many letters they are not uniformly strong/informed, and 2. it looks weird, sort of like a violation of implicit social norms.  Probably you won't cause yourself problems if you go as high as 5, but don't exceed that.

Comment: Do you really think most *postdoc* applications have 4 research letters?  My impression was that 3 was typical for new graduates and 4 or 5 was typical for TT applications.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: I seem to mostly see 4 research letters these days, at least for the most competitive applicants.  But you do see a lot with just 3 letters.